# glib2 hash table: GINT_TO_POINTER macro

Tags: glib

I don't think I understand the glib2's hash table, in particular, how to properly use GINT_TO_POINTER when both key and value are integers. I would think this is a use case for using `g_int_hash` and `g_int_equal` when you create a new hash table. However,the following snippet will seg faults.

```
#include <glib.h>

int main(void) {
    GHashTable * freq = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        g_hash_table_insert(freq, GINT_TO_POINTER(i), GINT_TO_POINTER(0));
    }
    g_hash_table_destroy(freq);
}
```

I know two ways to make it right: one is to create a hash table like this without changing anything else:

```
   GHashTable * freq = g_hash_table_new(g_direct_hash, g_direct_equal);
```

A second way is, keep creation as it is, but explicitly allocate space for both key and value:

```
   int * key = malloc(sizeof(int));
   int * value = malloc(sizeof(int));
```

then insert the key and value by casting it to (gpointer).

The second approach seems like a really tedious way of doing a  key value pair, is this the proper way of doing **int to int** mapping? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for [`g_int_hash()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Hash-Tables.html#g-int-hash) says:

> Note that this function acts on pointers to `gint`, not on `gint` directly: if your hash table's keys are of the form `GINT_TO_POINTER (n)`, use `g_direct_hash()` instead.

So yes, if you are doing int-to-int mapping, you should use `g_direct_hash()`, `g_direct_equal()`, and `GINT_TO_POINTER()`.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, if it only works for pointer to int, what would be the proper use-case for using `g_int_hash` function ... ?

Comment: the only use case for g_int_hash() and g_int_equal() is if you're using an allocated pointer to an integer as the key, for instance, if you're using a struct member.